# Consume Message from Multiple kafka hosts using multi bus kafka mass transit rider

Tags: .net-core, masstransit

I'm attempting to receive messages from multiple Kafka hosts. We're utilizing Kafka riders for message consumption. While I can successfully consume messages from the first bus, but I couldnt able to consume  the message from second bus and also no errors reported. Assistance with this issue would be greatly appreciated

Running Kafka locally using docker image . Implemented two buses to consume message from two hosts localhost:9094 and localhost:9095.

Expectation: should be able to consume message from both hosts

Actual: am able to consume from only localhost:9094

```
namespace KafkaConsumer;
using MassTransit;
using MassTransit.Kafka.Consumer.Consumers;
using MassTransit.Kafka.Contracts;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
// using MassTransit.Kafka.Consumer.Middlewares;
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            const string topicName = "test_topic";
            const string consumerGroup = "consumer-group-medium";
            const string kafkaBrokerServers = "localhost:9094";
            x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) =>
            {
                // cfg.UseExceptionLogger();

                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });

            x.AddRider(rider =>
            {
                rider.AddConsumer<KafkaMessageConsumer>();
                rider.UsingKafka((context, k) =>
                {
                    k.Host(kafkaBrokerServers);

                    k.TopicEndpoint<IMessage>(topicName, consumerGroup, e =>
                    {
                        e.ConfigureConsumer<KafkaMessageConsumer>(context);
                        e.CreateIfMissing();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        services.AddMassTransit<ISecondBus>(x =>
        {
            const string topicName1 = "test_topic";
            const string consumerGroup1 = "consumer-group-medium";
            const string kafkaBrokerServers1 = "localhost:9095";
            x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) =>
            {
                // cfg.UseExceptionLogger();
                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });
            x.AddConsumer<KafkaMessageConsumer1>();

            x.AddRider(rider =>
            {
                rider.AddConsumer<KafkaMessageConsumer1>();
                rider.UsingKafka((context, k) =>
                {
                    k.Host(kafkaBrokerServers1);
                    k.TopicEndpoint<IMessage>(topicName1, consumerGroup1, e =>
                    {
                        e.ConfigureConsumer<KafkaMessageConsumer1>(context);
                        e.CreateIfMissing();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        services.AddScoped<KafkaMessageConsumer>();
        services.AddScoped<KafkaMessageConsumer1>();
        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var busControl = provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>();
        await busControl.StartAsync(new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)).Token);
        Console.WriteLine("Started...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```